What DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) has the most (and best) features for free and with no account required?
I am a music enthusiast, making sheet music with Musescore, 8-bit music with Famistudio, and general music in the DAW known as LMMS. However, LMMS, while it is still being updated with new features, has not had a stable (as in ready for studio use) version for years.
So, I'm switching. But I have no clue what I should use. I believe I tried Cakewalk once, but it had so much stuff that my computer actually began to slow down. Yes, I do not have the most powerful computer.
As stated in the title, I wish for a DAW that is feature rich, and is free with no account required. Another thing: it must be able to run on a PC that is not in itself hardware feature rich. If LMMS is still the best DAW to go with, I'll stay with it. After all, it just might have an update, who knows.
P.S. I'd really like the DAW to have VST and SF3, SF2, and SFZ support by default.

I'm trying CakeWalk again. Slowly watching as the storage count on my PC crawls upwards. 86 GB left. 84 GB left. 80 GB left. Still willing to try something new (other than CakeWalk).

Ubuntu Studio is probably worth a look.

@WMRamadan I'll consider it. Although, I'd prefer to stay with Windows, as I use some Windows only applications, such as Visual Studio.
